# Filament - not able to listen to events

Tags: laravel, alpine.js, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have a custom page in filament whose view is:

```
<x-filament-panels::page>
    {{ $record->name }}

    @foreach ($record->unAnsweredChatSessions as $chatSession)
        <a href="#" wire:click="fetchMessages({{ $chatSession->id }})">
            {{ $chatSession->oldestMessage->message }}
        </a>
        <br />
    @endforeach

    @if ($selectChatSessionId > 0)
        <div>
            <h2>Chat Session with {{ $selectChatSessionId }}</h2>
            <div>
                @foreach ($selectedSessionMessages->messages as $message)
                    <div>
                        {{ $message->message }} <br><br>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <input type="text" wire:model="newMessage" />
            <input type="submit" wire:click="sendMessage" />
        </div>
    @endif
    <div x-on:foo.window="console.log('event is here')"></div>
</x-filament-panels::page>
```

Alternatively, I have also tried, listening in js like:

```
@script
    <script type="module">
        document.addEventListener('livewire:init', () => {
            Livewire.on('foo', (event) => {
                console.log('captured event here?')
            });
        });
    </script>
@endscript
```

and I am dispatching the foo event from a livewire component from the frontend (not filament) like:

1. Using alpine

```
<button @click="$dispatch('foo')" wire:click="sendMessage">Send</button>
```

2. Using Livewire

```
$this->dispatch('foo');
```

Also, tried with Laravel events and using echo in the filament custom page view but, I get an error saying `Laravel Echo not found` in the console. Tried both in view and in the class like:

```
 public function getListeners()
    {
        return [
            "echo:adminchatnotification,.new-chat-for-{$this->selectChatSessionId}" => 'fetchMessages',
        ];
    }
```

and

```
@script
    <script type="module">
        Echo.private(`new-chat-for-{{ $selectChatSessionId }}`)
            .listen('adminchatnotification', (e) => {
                $wire.$refresh()
            });
    </script>
@endscript

why I am not able to receive this event in filament?
I must be missing something very basic here?
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that Filament Pages aren't Livewire Components, so you cannot use Livewire Events in them.

Possible work around is to create a Livewire Component which you place on the page, and then put any Event logic there so that it can capture them.

Answer (score 0):

On PHP:

```
$this->dispatch('foo', message : 'hello');
```

On JS:

```
document.addEventListener('livewire:init', () => {
       Livewire.on('foo', (data) => {
        console.log('Received custom event:', data);
       });
    });
```

More info: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events